# Android : Relativelayout in Framelayout not showing up (Custom Camera Preview Screen)

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout

I need same as I attached image file Its Camera Preview Screen  : I want to design two transparent layout over framelayout so it looks like this, but when I run it show only camera screen(Framelayout). It not showing two relative layouts.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="01"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Status:"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
            android:src="@drawable/heart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:text="125 Likes"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="STREAMING" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
            android:text="24 Viewers"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#77000000"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_record"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/view_video_big" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/swipe_camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your image??

Comment: Why did you give a weight to your parent FrameLayout??

Comment: i have just uploaded my image. just see

Comment: i have removed weight . still it shows only Framelayout when i run. i am unable to see two relative layout on screen which is transpernt

Comment: @SandyAngel You mean to say that your both relative layout didn't displayed??

Comment: @SandyAngel is it showing in preview in eclipse ide

Comment: it showing, please check in real device.

Comment: @SandyAngel I have tested its working.. You just need to test in your real device rather than run in emulator.

Comment: yes,relative layout didn't displayed.  it showing in preview in eclipse ide but not when i run in emulator or device :(

Comment: ok..wait i will post my answer..

Comment: in code how you are loading background image?

Comment: @RobinHood. Framelayout is my camera preview screen. when i run it. it shows only camera. but not both relative layout. :(

Comment: @SandyAngel In which device u r running your app?

Comment: @SandyAngel posted my answer just change like that and let me know if you have any doubts..

Comment: @SandyAngel In your coding have you set visibility **GONE** for ur both relative layouts anywhere???

Comment: Why are you using Frame Layout. You could use Relative Layout as the Parent Layout because this will also show the desired result. I only use frame layout whenever I need to bring the child views to front or back at runtime.

Comment: @SandyAngel have ur problem solved now?

Comment: @SandyAngel set background image for Framelayout statically in your xml file and check and run

Comment: @SandyAngel give some feedback

Comment: @Piyush I am applying all the answer to my code. thanks for replay

Comment: @SandyAngel No but have you set image for Framelayout dynamically?

Comment: @Piyush.. Its not Image in the backgroud its video recoder preview screen

Comment: @SandyAngel Show me your code. And if it is Video recorder screen then you must be used SurfaceView.

Comment: @ PiYusH GuPtA @Harsit Rathhi @ Robin hood and All who tried to solved : Thank you so much for your try. Thanks Again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add ids to the two `RelativeLlayouts` in layout file..

and get the view object by like this

```
    RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topRelativeLayout);
    RelativeLayout layout2=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomRelativeLayout);
```

and add this line in your onCreate and test once..

```
    layout1.bringToFront();
    layout2.bringToFront();
```

Comment: @HarshitRathi SO purpose is to give answer and comment which is perfectly right answer. If any body has doubts or anything problem then he/she can comment to other SO user's answer. So don't behave like kid dude.

Comment: @kalyan pvs : Its worked, i have just added id and get view object as you mentioned  before frame layout get view object, Thank you so much. you made my day :)

Comment: @Kalyan pvs : you are awesomeeeee.. !

Answer (score 0):

Try this first of all you have to set your background image to `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="01"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Status:"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
            android:src="@drawable/heart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:text="125 Likes"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="STREAMING" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
            android:text="24 Viewers"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#77000000"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_record"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/view_video_big" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/swipe_camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

or follow this [link](http://cvirus.tumblr.com/post/22717059570/howto-overlay-controls-and-text-over-androids-camera).

Comment: You can't set orientation for **FrameLayout**.

Comment: @Harshit Rathi : Framlayout not contain any images it contains camera preview screen :(

Comment: @SandyAngel I have mentioned a link in my answer for what you want.

Comment: @Kalyan pvs : i am just checking it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @SandyAngel have you follow link which i mentioned.